# Adding up time in php

Tags: php, time

I want to add up time in php but after hours of google'ing and trying out im still unable to find a solution.

my values are:

```
$newTotal = '00:45:00';
$oldTotal = '00:16:00';
```

I want to add those two up which make 01:01:00.

Can you give me an example i'm getting really desperate! :p

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep a start date for minimum error.

```
<?php
$origin   = '00:00:00';
$newTotal = '00:45:00';
$oldTotal = '00:16:00';

$added = strtotime($newTotal) + (strtotime($oldTotal) - strtotime($origin));

echo date('H:i:s', $added );
```

output :

```
01:01:00
```

**Note**, if your time is more than 23:59:59 after adding, you will get wrong result.

Comment: Is it also possible to add the date to it? So when its past 24 hours it adds an day?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to turn them into Unix timestamps, then add them as integers:

```
$newTotal = '00:45:00';
$oldTotal = '00:16:00';

$total = strtotime($newTotal) + strtotime($oldTotal);
```

To format it as `hh:mm:ss` again, use `date()`:

```
echo date('H:i:s', $total);
```

This gives:

> 01:01:00

Comment: @Tufan Yes, I did. Have you tried it yourself? It works fine for me.

Comment: @user1502363 Did you try it with the strings posted in your OP, or with other ones? I tested my code before posting here and it gave the correct time.

Comment: I copied it exactly as you posted it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If these values always look like that, you could break them down with a substr()

```
$hours1 = substr($newTotal, 0, 2);
```

etc. And then simply add up the seconds, do a divide and mod and bubble up to the hours, and voila!

```
$secondstotal = $seconds1+$seconds2; 
$restseconds = $secondstotal % 60;
$minutesfromseconds = floor($restseconds / 60);

$minutestotal = $minutes1+$minutes2+$minutesfromseconds;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without time function:

```php
function sumtotal($a,$b) {
    $i = explode(':',$a);
    $j = explode(':',$b); // 0hh:1mm:2ss
    $k = array(0,0,0,0); // 0days:1hours:2minutes:3seconds
    $k[3] = $i[2]+$j[2];
    $k[2] = (int)($k[3]/60)+$i[1]+$j[1];
    $k[1] = (int)($k[2]/60)+$i[0]+$j[0];
    $k[0] = (int)($k[1]/24);
    $k[3] %= 60;
    $k[2] %= 60;
    $k[1] %= 24;
    if ($k[3]<10) $k[3] = '0'.$k[3];
    if ($k[2]<10) $k[2] = '0'.$k[2];
    if ($k[1]<10) $k[1] = '0'.$k[1];
    return $k[0].' days : '.$k[1].' hours : '.$k[2].' minutes : '.$k[3].' seconds';
}

$newTotal = '01:45:21';
$oldTotal = '03:16:56';
echo sumtotal($newTotal,$oldTotal); // result:  0 days : 05 hours : 02 minutes : 17 seconds
```